# RichRelevance SDK internally giving Null Pointer Exception. How to fix it?

Tags: android, e-commerce

```
// method to set the richRelevance configuration
public static void initializeRichRelevance(Context context) {
    final SharedPreference sharedPreference = SharedPreference.getInstance(context);
    ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration(APIKEY, CLIENTKEY);
    config.setApiClientSecret("");
    Log.e("Member_ID",getStringValue(sharedPreference.getSharedPref("member_id")));
    config.setUserId(getStringValue(sharedPreference.getSharedPref("member_id")));
    config.setSessionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    RichRelevance.init(context, config);

    // Enable all logging
    RichRelevance.setLoggingLevel(RRLog.VERBOSE);
    Logger.logDebug("RichRelevance", "initilization Done...");
}

// method to fetch recommended product from richRelevance
private void initRichRelevance() {
    RichRelevance.setLoggingLevel(RRLog.VERBOSE);
    Placement placement = new Placement(Placement.PlacementType.ITEM, "recs_2mh");
    PlacementsRecommendationsBuilder placementsRecommendationsBuilder = new PlacementsRecommendationsBuilder();
    placementsRecommendationsBuilder.setPlacements(placement);
    placementsRecommendationsBuilder.setProductIds(idProduct);
    placementsRecommendationsBuilder.setCallback(new Callback<PlacementResponseInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlacementResponseInfo placementResponseInfo) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            if (placementResponseInfo != null && placementResponseInfo.getPlacements() != null) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(placementResponseInfo.getRawJson().toString());
                    requestAPI(jsonObject);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Utils.logExceptionCrashLytics(e);
                    Logger.logError("JsonException", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(com.richrelevance.Error error) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>          at com.richrelevance.internal.net.HttpUrlConnectionExecutor.getConnection(HttpUrlConnectionExecutor.java:87)
>          at com.richrelevance.internal.net.HttpUrlConnectionExecutor.execute(HttpUrlConnectionExecutor.java:40)
>          at com.richrelevance.internal.net.WebRequestManager.execute(WebRequestManager.java:172)
>          at com.richrelevance.internal.net.WebRequestManager$1.run(WebRequestManager.java:193)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>          at com.richrelevance.internal.net.WebRequestManager$2$1.run(WebRequestManager.java:219)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: We have no clue where to start since we have no clue what your code looks like, or if you even have any code.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Please see my question now.